# jQuery:Case insensitive :contains

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

How can i to change below function for case insensitive search all div elements(div[id*=music]) which has a link contains search_text;

```
function search(el){
    var search_text = $(el).val();
    //if(!search_text) return false;
    var search_block = $('div.music_box');
    search_block.children('div[id*=music]:hidden').show();
    search_block.children('div[id*=music]').filter(':not(:has(a:contains('+search_text+')))').hide();
    console.log(search_block.children('div[id*=music]'));
}
```

**jQuery v1.10.2**

Comment: Don't over-use DOM selectors. Use a filtering callback, case-insensitive string comparison is trivial there.

Comment: Bergi, can you to show me example with filtering for my function? )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
jQuery.expr[':'].Contains = function(a,i,m){
    return (a.textContent || a.innerText || "").toUpperCase().indexOf(m[3].toUpperCase())>=0;
};
```

and then you ca use it like: `$("element:Contains")`